# In C, what happens when the condition for a for loop aren't met at the beginning?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

For example, what happens if I say:

```
for(i = 2; i < 2; i++)
```

Obviously, this is a useless for loop, but maybe i = a, and a is set by something else. So what happens in this case?

Comment: Couldn't you write some code in about two minutes that would answer this for you?

Comment: https://ideone.com/guKsdG

Comment: @KenWhite My compiler is acting up right now, otherwise I would've tested it.

Comment: How on Earth does a compiler *act up*? That's nonsense. You just figured you didn''t need to do anything to find an answer yourself because you could just ask here and get an answer. That's horrific. It's fine to need help sometimes, but don't be totally helpless. Learn to make an  effort to figure out things yourself instead of having your hand held. (I'm actually betting that this is a question being asked in an early programming class assignment, and you're just getting a homework answer. Do you even have a compiler?)

Comment: There is not even need to compile anything. Any simpel search would point you at some C tutorial or book.

Comment: "The dog ate my compiler"

Comment: Don't they teach "desk checking" any more?

Comment: @KenWhite Fair enough. I asked this question last night when I was very tired, and wasn't thinking straight. Probably shouldn't be programming that late anyway. And you're right it's related to an assignment, but it's not a question. It's actually a bigger assignment, and I wasn't sure if it would work. Honestly, I'm not sure why I didn't just test it or look it up. I have no excuse. I deserve my downvotes and shame.

Comment: To be fair, although this may have been a bad question, 5 years later this page serves as a fast answer for even ppl with decent amounts of programming experience who want to quickly double-check this fact without having to create a test script themselves. So, for what it's worth, this question has provided helpful information to *at least* 3 ppl so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither iteration of the loop will be executed.

In fact this loop (provided that the condition has no side effects)

```
for(i = 2; i < 2; i++) { /* ... */ }
```

is equivalent to this statement

```
i = 2;
```

Answer (score 4):

The condition of a for loop is checked before every iteration, including the first one; so your loop's body will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The way **for loop** works is it checks for condition (in your case `i < 2`) and executes whatever is between `{  }` or whatever code on following lines

As you are initializing `i` to `2` the condition fails immediately and nothing executes.

Essentially whatever code that is inside of **for loop** never executes.

Answer (score 0):

In a `for` loop, the condition is evaluated before the first iteration. This means that in your example, the content of the loop would not be executed because `i` is already greater than or equal to `2`.

Example code path:

1. Set `i = 2`.
2. Check if `i < 2`.
3. Exit loop because step 2 evaluated to false.

`i` would still be modified, however, as the variable initialization (i.e. `i = 2`) still occurs before the condition is checked.