# Two sum - Doesn't work

Tags: java, hashmap

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
Consider input [3,2,4] and target is 6. I added (3,0) and (2,1) to the map and when I come to 4 and calculate value as 6 - 4 as 2 and when I check if 2 is a key present in map or not, it does not go in if loop.

I should get output as [1,2] which are the indices for 2 and 4 respectively

```
  public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int len = nums.length;
    int[] arr = new int[2];
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0;i < len; i++)
    {
        int value = nums[i] - target;
        if(map.containsKey(value))
        {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            arr[0] = value;
            arr[1] = map.get(value);
            return arr;
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(nums[i],i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I don't get where the problem is, please help me out

Comment: What's your input?  Based on the problem description, it sounds more like you need to have a double `for-loop` to compare each value with each other value to determine if the sum to the expected target

Comment: *don't work* is not a useful problem description, and you haven't described any *problem*. What is the problem you're having with the code you've posted? This site is for **specific questions**, and there is nothing specific about *don''t work* or a *problem* you don't describe.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: What *problem description* are you seeing that we're not? *don't work*? Does 250K rep magically endow psychic powers? If so, I need to work a lot harder here. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Actually, the first two paragraphs which I assume are the assignment requirements. About the only thing that 250K rep gives you is depression over the how much people aren't willing to help themselves these days ;P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I only have 350 rep and I'm already feeling that... 

OP: You should update your question with input, expected output, actual output, etc

Comment: I'd learn how to use a debugger and then step through it.  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: @MadProgrammer: No, that depression comes far before 250K. I've had it for ages. ;-) I just [commented about it earlier tonight](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42708412/62576). As far as the problem description, I didn't catch it; it looked like part of the copy/paste of the assignment, because the poster included it in the same paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice. Consider input [3,2,4] and target is 6. I added (3,0) and (2,1) to the map and when I come to 4 and calculate value as 6 - 4 as 2 and when I check if 2 is a key present in map or not, it does not go in if loop.

Okay, let's take a step back for a second.

You have a list of values, `[3,2,4]`. You need to know which two will add up `6`, well, by looking at it we know that the answer should be `[1,2]` (values `2` and `4`)

The question now is, how do you do that programmatically

The solution is (to be honest), very simple, you need two loops, this allows you to compare each element in the list with every other element in the list

```
for (int outter = 0; outter < values.length; outter++) {
    int outterValue = values[outter];
    for (int inner = 0; inner < values.length; inner++) { 
        if (inner != outter) { // Don't want to compare the same index
            int innerValue = values[inner];
            if (innerValue + outterValue == targetValue) {
                // The outter and inner indices now form the answer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While not highly efficient (yes, it would be easy to optimise the inner loop, but given the OP's current attempt, I forewent it), this is VERY simple example of how you might achieve what is actually a very common problem

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = nums[i] - target;
```

Your subtraction is backwards, as `nums[i]` is probably smaller than `target`.  So `value` is getting set to a negative number.  The following would be better:

```
int value = target - nums[i];
```

(Fixing this won't fix your whole program, but it explains why you're getting the behavior that you are.)

Answer (score 0):

This code for twoSum might help you. For the inputs of integer array, it will return the indices of the array if the sum of the values = target.

```
public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
     int[] indices = new int[2];
     outerloop:
     for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){
             if((nums[i]+nums[j]) == target){
                 indices[0] = i;
                 indices[1] = j;
                 break outerloop;
             }
         }
     }
     return indices;
 }
```

You can call the function using

```
 int[] num = {1,2,3};
 int[] out = twoSum(num,4);
 System.out.println(out[0]);
 System.out.println(out[1]);
```

Output:

0
   2

Answer (score 0):

You should update the way you compute for the value as follows:

```
int value = target - nums[i];
```

You can also check [this video](https://youtu.be/B8PURPqVmJQ) if you want to better visualize it. It includes Brute force and Linear approach: